# Can't get Events from 3Dconnexion SpaceNavigator using Qt 4.8 with Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, 3d, mouse

I am developing a 3D application using Qt 4.8 under Linux. Now I need to support a 3d mouse (3Dconnexion SpaceNavigator). The SDK that comes with it is rather old school, using X11 to retrieve events.

I am using the sample code provided with the SDK and tried to incorporate it with Qt 4.8. It looks like setting up the Mouse is working (as far as I can tell from the debug output), yet I don't get any XEvents with QWidget::x11Event(XEvent*).

I already found solutions circumventing the SDK using libudev or libusb, both which are currently not available for me :/

Maybe someone already has a solution to this specific problem? I cannot imagine everyone using X11 nowadays :)

Heres the Qt setup code I am using, debug output look like it's working:

```
Display* pDisplay = QX11Info::display();

Atom event_motion  = XInternAtom( pDisplay, "MotionEvent", TRUE );
Atom event_press   = XInternAtom( pDisplay, "ButtonPressEvent", TRUE );
Atom event_release = XInternAtom( pDisplay, "ButtonReleaseEvent", TRUE );
Atom event_command = XInternAtom( pDisplay, "CommandEvent", TRUE );


std::cout << "MotionEvent: " << event_motion << std::endl;
std::cout << "ButtonPressEvent: " << event_press << std::endl;
std::cout << "ButtonReleaseEvent: " << event_release << std::endl;
std::cout << "CommandEvent: " << event_command << std::endl;

Atom ActualType;
int ActualFormat;
unsigned long NItems, BytesReturn;

Window root = RootWindow( pDisplay, DefaultScreen(pDisplay) );
std::cout << "root: " << std::hex << "0x" << root << std::dec << std::endl;
unsigned char* p_property;

Window app_window = (Window) this->window()->winId();

XGetWindowProperty( pDisplay, root, event_command, 0, 1, FALSE, 
    AnyPropertyType, &ActualType, &ActualFormat, &NItems, &BytesReturn, &p_property );

if (0!=p_property)
{
    Window wnd = *(Window*) p_property;
    XFree( p_property );

    std::cout << "magellan window number: " << std::hex << wnd << std::dec << std::endl;

    XTextProperty wnd_name;
    XGetWMName( pDisplay, wnd, &wnd_name );
    std::cout << "magellan window name: " << wnd_name.value << std::endl; 

    XGetWMName( pDisplay, app_window, &wnd_name );
    std::cout << "Found window property: " << wnd_name.value << " (" << std::hex << app_window << std::dec << ")" << std::endl;

    XEvent CommandMessage;
    CommandMessage.type = ClientMessage;
    CommandMessage.xclient.format = 16;
    CommandMessage.xclient.send_event = FALSE;
    CommandMessage.xclient.display = pDisplay;
    CommandMessage.xclient.window = wnd;
    CommandMessage.xclient.message_type = event_command;

    CommandMessage.xclient.data.s[0] = (short) XHigh32( app_window );
    CommandMessage.xclient.data.s[1] = (short) XLow32( app_window );
    CommandMessage.xclient.data.s[2] = 27695;

    if (0!=XSendEvent( pDisplay, wnd, FALSE, 0x0000, &CommandMessage ))
    {
        std::cout << "Sent event to SpaceMouse" << std::endl;
    }

    XSelectInput( pDisplay, app_window, NoEventMask );
}
```

Thanks for any hints :)

Comment: Just as a side-note: the SpaceNavigator 3D mouse itself does work, so drivers etc. are up and running.

Comment: [This](http://spacenav.sourceforge.net/) might be of some use.  I've used very similar code in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering around with the 3d mouse even more, I came to the conclusion that the "official" way leads to a dead-end. Linux seems to not be properly supported anymore by the driver.

So I bit the bullet and I am now gathering data from the 3d mouse using /dev/input/event under Linux, which is at least UI independent. I open the device and read data in a seperate thread (device is polled in regular intervals).

This works quite well so far.